# Drake and the Jupyter notebook runtime is not installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, drake

I have ubuntu 20.04.
I already install drake and Jupiter notebook, but
when I try `python3 -m pydrake.tutorials` I have got this error:

```
ERROR: the Jupyter notebook runtime is not installed!

Drake offers Python tutorials that can be previewed and executed as Jupyter
notebooks online with no need for local installation. To run Drake's tutorials
online, refer to the `Drake Tutorials <https://drake.mit.edu/>`_ website.

Alternatively, to run Drake's tutorials locally from an
`installed <https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html>`_ copy of Drake,
run ``python3 -m pydrake.tutorials`` to launch a Jupyter browser.

Be sure your ``PYTHONPATH`` has been set per the installation instructions,
e.g., via ``source env/bin/activate`` in the
`pip instructions <https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html>`_.

If you haven't done so already, you'll also need to install the Jupyter
notebook package on your system:

- For pip or macOS, use: ``pip install notebook``.
- For Ubuntu, use ``sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook``.
```

When I try run `jupyter notebook`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/home/dmitriy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command helped me `python -m pip install markupsafe==2.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The path `/home/dmitriy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/...` indicates that you have local pip packages installed, but are not using a virtual environment (venv).  It's likely that those packages are interfering with Jupyter's runtime environment.